# Why, Sending nil as parameters from Objc C to swift class initializer, replaces nil parameters with new objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I created this Swift class:

```
@objc public class Tester: NSObject {
    private var name: String
    private var user: Users
    init(string:String, user: Users) {
        print(user.empId)
        print(user.name)
        self.user = user
        self.name = string
        super.init()
    }
}
```

I call the initializer from Obj C like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSString * nilString = nil;
    Users * nilUser = nil;
    Tester * test = [[Tester alloc] initWithString:nilString user:nilUser];

    return YES;
}
```

Here I pass `nil` for the parameters to the Swift initializer. Ideally I expect this to crash as the initializer only accepts non-`nil` values.

[image]

But what actually happens is, when the execution point reaches inside the initializer, new parameter objects are created:

[image]

The `nil` string becomes `""` and the `User` variable that was `nil` is now pointing to an object.

But for a property like this

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) SomeClass * object;
```

where

```
object = nil;
```

When I call this object from swift,

```
let x = object.someGetter;
```

This crashes.

At one point, If I pass nil to some non null, it works and at another point, it crashes. Why does this weird behavior exist? If for some reasons, my parameters are nil, and passed to nonnull, I would like this to crash. So that I can fix things.

EDIT: This became so unexpected, further trying to play with this code.

[image]

The string parameter was actually as string, but the User shows uninitialized, hence manipulations on string worked well, but the user object, took the changes but did not showed them back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So there are three questions:

- first, why does accessing the user properties not crash,
- second, why is there an empty string instead of a `nil` one,
- third, why does assigning a property (of a custom class) crash

I'll answer all of them :-)

### 1. Accessing the Users properties

Swift uses Objective C messaging when accessing the properties of the `Users` class, (I assume - `Users` is an ObjC-Class as seen in the debugger output; base class `NSObject`). 
In the disassembly view, one can see this:

```
0x1000018be <+78>:   movq   0x3e6e2b(%rip), %rsi      ; "empId"
   ....
0x1000018d7 <+103>:  callq  0x100361b10               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
```

Since `objc_msgSend` supports nil messaging, the call does not fail.

### 2. Empty String magic

When calling the Swift initializer from Objective C, the bridging code creates the following:

```
0x100001f45 <+53>: callq  0x100021f50               
; static (extension in Foundation):
;Swift.String._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSString>) -> Swift.String
   ....
0x100001f5b <+75>: callq  0x100001870               
; TestCalling.Tester.init (string : Swift.String, user : __ObjC.ObjCUser) -> TestCalling.Tester at SwiftClass.swift:14
```

The interesting part here is the `_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC` call. This will internally call the Swift.String function `_cocoaStringToSwiftString_NonASCII`, and checking the source code ([here, line 48](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringBridge.swift)), you can see the following:

```
@inline(never) @_semantics("stdlib_binary_only") // Hide the CF dependency
func _cocoaStringToSwiftString_NonASCII(
  _ source: _CocoaString
) -> String {
  let cfImmutableValue = _stdlib_binary_CFStringCreateCopy(source)
  let length = _stdlib_binary_CFStringGetLength(cfImmutableValue)
  let start = _stdlib_binary_CFStringGetCharactersPtr(cfImmutableValue)

  return String(_StringCore(
    baseAddress: start,
    count: length,
    elementShift: 1,
    hasCocoaBuffer: true,
    owner: unsafeBitCast(cfImmutableValue, to: Optional<AnyObject>.self)))
}
```

The function always returns a new `Swift.String` object, in our case an empty one! So, again no crash.

### 3. Property access

When accessing a custom property, e.g. assigning it to a variable:

```
let x:SomeClass = object.someGetter;
```

the following happens:

1. The return value of `someGetter` will be retained (`objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue`) -- this does not crash
2. The returned object will be implicitly unwrapped -- which then crashes

If `x` were a weak property, or an optional, the code wouldn't crash. Even when using type inference, it does *not* crash (on my machine, swift 4):

```
let x = object.someGetter;
```

This is, because the inferred type of `x` is an optional `SomeClass?` unless the property itself is declared as `nonnull`:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong, nonnull) SomeClass * object;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the property access part? I don't fully understand "The return value of someGetter will be retained (objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue) -- this does not crash" and "The returned object will be implicitly unwrapped -- which then crashes". Why will the return value of someGetter be retained and why it be implicitly unwrapped?

Answer (score 1):

When you say the string is `""` and the user is an object, it looks like you're just relying on the debugger's variable view for this, correct? Because the console output clearly shows `nil` twice.

What's happening here is the generated code for the initializer doesn't actually do anything that would crash if the values are `nil`. Semantically speaking, yes, it's invalid, but the actual machine code isn't doing something that relies on the non-`nil` assumption. The calls to `print()` work because, I assume, the code that converts the arguments into `Any` existentials happens to work even though the values are unexpectedly `nil`, and produce a `nil` `Any`.

As for the debugger view, it's a debugger, it's just doing the best it can to interpret the variables, but it's not actually running the Swift standard library. I'm not entirely sure why the `string` variable is showing up as `""`, I guess because it's always showing a string representation and it determines that it has no data (and a string with no data is `""`). As for `user`, it actually shows it as `0x0000000000000000` which is correct, that means it's the null pointer (i.e. `nil`).

And then finally, `let x = object.someGetter` does crash, because the resulting code depends on the value being non-`nil` (specifically, it's presumably calling `swift_retain()` or `swift_unknownRetain()` on the value, which requires the argument to be non-`nil` as it dereferences the pointer).

Comment: "Because the console output clearly shows nil twice." this was for line 15, 16, that prints, some properties on Users object, not the parameters.

Comment: I guess because it's always showing a string representation and it determines that it has no data (and a string with no data is "") - It tried  to play with this,  and I think the string here is initialized. Check the updates on question.